# Error: key $$hashKey must not start with '$' (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, meteor

Attempting to add something to my collection when I got the following error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'submit' Error: key $$hashKey must not start with '$'
```

Each meal object :

```
$scope.meal = {
  items:[],
  createdBy:null
};
```

Here is my submit function inside my controller :

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();

  if(currentUserId!=null) {
    if($scope.checkValidity()==false) {
      alert("Need to fill out valid calories and/or items!");
    }
    else {
      $scope.meal.createdBy = currentUserId;
      Meteor.call("submit", $scope.meal);
      alert("has just been submitted");
    }
  }
  else {
    alert("You must sign in first!");
  }
}
```

I've cross examined my submit function numerous times but I can't seem to find an error. I've looked on google as well of this error and it seems like its a little over my head especially because I'm still a Angular beginner. In the meantime, I'll attempt to find more information.

Found some information : https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/299

Seems like they fixed it from the comments? Yet the same problem has come up..Check it out.

Comment: Does the solution they suggest, i.e., `Meteor.call('submit', angular.copy($scope.meal))`, solve the issue?

Comment: OMG..I tried that last night and it wasn't working. But I just realized I was doing something wrong..omg the problem was right there and I just didn't see it..Well, I guess a new pair of eyes always helps! Thank you so much! Worked beautifully after I fixed some syntax issue that I was having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to add a object to the items of the meal, try using:

```
  $scope.meal.items.push(angular.copy($scope.newItem));
```

And when you call

```
 Meteor.call("submit", angular.copy($scope.meal));
```

this is because angular uses a reference to track the object

Comment: Thanks fam! @Esteban