# Need an Alternative approach (Meteor + AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, meteor

A problem that has come up during when the making of my application is that, AngularJS does not allow an object to have an array.

I'm making a calorie counter where the user will be able to add as many items to each meal. Each meal object is represented by the following :

```
$scope.meal = {
 items:[],
 createdBy:null
};
```

And the reason, I'm giving the meal object an array is because I want the user to have an option to add as many items as possible. Here is the layout:

```
Button [ADD ITEM]  //User clicks on it 

Item 1 [_________]
Calories [________]

Button [ADD ITEM]
```

Basically, every time the user clicks add item, he/she is attempting to add another item in the meal which is why I'm using an array. Here is what is happening in the view : (Using the ng-repeat directive to have the HTML printed out again)

```
<div id="left" ng-controller="formCtrl">
   Enter the number of items in your meal :
   <br><br>
   <div ng-repeat="item in meal.items">
      <label>Item {{$index+1}} :
         <input type="text" class="item" ng-model="item.name"><br>
      </label>
      <label>Calories :
         <input type="number" class="calories" ng-model="item.cal"><br>
      </label>
      <br>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <button ng-click="addItem()" id="itemButton">+ Item</button>
    <button ng-click="submit()" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Not sure if this is needed but here is the addItem() :

```
  $scope.addItem = function() {
   $scope.meal.items.push({
    name:null,
    cal:null
  });
}
```

I've posted another question on stack asking for a solution to the AngularJS problem that I'm currently experiencing. Check it out here : [Error: key $$hashKey must not start with '$' (AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173465/error-key-hashkey-must-not-start-with-angularjs)

I've also posted an issue to Urigo/Angular-Meteor but I'm not sure how long it will take to fix it. In the meantime, I've been attempting to think of alternative ways of going about this problem. Basically, attempting to have the same functionality but change the array portion of it.

Comment: Technically, AngularJS **does** allow objects to have arbitrary nesting. However, using an array in `ng-repeat` makes angular add a `$$hashKey` attribute to the array. Normally, this attribute does not cause any problems. However, if you pass the object with this attribute to Meteor methods, it causes the problem you pointed to. Making a copy of the object (or just removing the `$$hashKey` before passing the object to `Meteor.submit` should fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah, that worked exactly! I was just making a syntax mistake. Ahhh I feel so dumb lol...anyways, thank you so much! So happy right now haha..

Comment: Err ... glad to help. :-?